# How do I change a scene into a chapter in Scrivener?

Tags: scrivener

When I started using Scrivener a few weeks ago, I added chapters as scenes by mistake. Now I want to make them separate chapters. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the [project template](http://howtoscrivener.com/scrivener-templates/) you are using. Scrivener is a very flexible platform and every project can be customized in many ways.

The base unit of text they call a "scrivening", and this is what it is--a chunk of text. They can be organized into folders, just like files.

I am using the Novel/Manuscript template which came with my version of Scrivener at the time I bought it a few years back. In my template, a scene is a base unit, and everything is built around that: scenes are organized into chapters (folders), chapters are organized into parts (also folders), and parts are just that--parts of the novel, which is essentially one huge folder, where everything is kept. It is usually called *Draft* or, in my version, for some reason, *Manuscript*.

When it comes to *scrivening*/file management, Scrivener mimics any and all operating systems there are: in the *Binder* you can move your pieces in and out of folders, create new folders/texts, copy and paste them, etc.

Compare the structure of the chapter in your template to the structure of a scene and remodel accordingly. It might be as simple as selecting the chapter you want to turn into a scene in the *Binder*, right-clicking on it and selecting "convert to file" option.

> Quick and Dirty Way: Duplicate a blank chapter in your template which
>   contains a few blank scenes, then make as many scenes inside of it as
>   you need, copy-paste your text into those scenes, then move them where
>   they belong--different chapter. I would keep the blank Chapter with
>   blank scenes in it in your book/draft/manuscript folder just for that
>   purpose. This is what I do: when I start a new chapter, I just duplicate the blank one,
>   then write scenes within it.

Comment: @"convert to folder' & 'convert to file'